# Google Sheets Import XML: Amazon size and price

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How to solve this error would help me a lot [Getting this error when I try to import the price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLYoM.png)

This is formula I'm using =IMPORTXML(H2,"//span[@aria-hidden='true']")

Amazon product link - https://www.amazon.in/Lymio-Womens-Regular-Top-D-476_White/dp/B09FFFNJ4M/ref=sr_1_8?fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=1968542031&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_p=629c266a-f7c9-4115-888e-7c3bfa05b9f6&pf_rd_r=VVYDPRSF90K5RNQ4KPQV&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-3&pf_rd_t=30901&qid=1641063740&rnid=11301356031&s=apparel&sr=1-8&th=1&psc=1

And need to import the size correctly? [size error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn2v8.png)
Formula I'm using --> =IMPORTXML(H2,"//span[@class='a-dropdown-prompt']")
Also how can I import product images as well?

Answer (score -1):

size:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//span[@aria-hidden='true']"), 
 "where Col1 matches '[A-Z]' limit 1", 0)
```

price:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//span[@aria-hidden='true']"), 
 "where Col1 matches '.+\d+' limit 1 offset 1", 0)
```

[image]

images:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@id='altImages']//img/@src"), 
 "where Col1 contains 'media'"), 3))
```

[image]

Comment: how to get this image src url? Need the image url for the first image

<img alt="Lymio Women&amp;#39;s Regular Top" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71wJkFys1dL._UY741_.jpg" data-old-hires="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/7

Answer (score -1):

Size:

```
=importxml(A1,"//span[@id='dropdown_selected_size_name']")
```

Price:

```
=index(importxml(A1,"//span[@class='a-price a-text-price a-size-medium apexPriceToPay']"),1)
```